# SortInPlace expression was too complex - Xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

After updating to Xcode 7, my iOS App stopped compiling (due to several "changes"), however I've come up with something I don't know how to make any simpler. I need to sort an Array depending on the three following conditions:

```
        appDelegate.all_breeds!.sortInPlace { (a, b) -> Bool in
            (a.breedNameES == nil) ||
            (b.breedNameES == nil) ||
            (a.breedNameES! < b.breedNameES!)
        }
```

Basically I need to see if either the breed A in spanish is nil, OR if the breed B in spanish is nil, otherwise I need to compare both breeds, and sort them in alphabetical order.

This had worked without problems until I updated to xCode 7, now the error I get is

```
Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; 
consider breaking up the expression into distinct subexpressions.
```

The problem is I can't break it into subexpressions, it's as basic as I can think of.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Appearently part of the problem was that Breed was a struct in my AppDelegate, which forced the compiler to iterate through all the structs to find it. This made that the expression took more time to compile.

Comment: What type have the array elements? It might help to provide explicit type annotations in the closure, e.g. `{ (a : Breed, b : Breed) -> Bool in ... }`

Comment: Your code compiles without warning for me in Xcode 7. It even works ok in a Playground, I've [tested](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFnY_0GRRUtBMZnAM6YJS6HHuOFMk2BY1Js) with a sample struct.

Comment: I just tried with a simple struct and couldn't reproduce the error

Comment: Do you have Swift Compiler Optimizations enabled?

Comment: Breed was a Struct in the AppDelegate, after adding (a : AppDelegate.Breed, b : AppDelegate.Breed) as suggested by Martin, it compiled again. Martin if you could please post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

can have various reasons. One is that the compiler could not infer the
types of expressions automatically from the context. In that case it
helps to add explicit type annotations. In your case

```
appDelegate.all_breeds!.sortInPlace { (a : AppDelegate.Breed, b : AppDelegate.Breed) -> Bool in
    (a.breedNameES == nil) ||
    (b.breedNameES == nil) ||
    (a.breedNameES! < b.breedNameES!)
}
```

Comment: @Waclock: You are welcome. Btw, note that your closure does not provide a ["strict weak ordering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) as required by the `sortInPlace()` method: `a < b` and `b < a` can both be true.